# apache started port 80 busy XAMPP

Tags: mysql, apache, error-handling

I cant find the problem. I tried to change listen port til 8080 and 81 but that doesnt seem to work.

I do not have skype installed. IIS is not running.

Msql works fine. But the apache stopped working after i restarted/shutoff and on my pc, so i think something is blocking or bussy on port 80.

Screenshot of my pc proccess: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rudtZ.jpg

ERROR msg from xampp:

WARNING: terminating worker thread 0
Apache started [Port 80]